# TRichEdit замена текста в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Процедура заменяет загруженные в TRichEdit слова - на указанные в словаре `tblDictionary` (грузится из XML). Как сделать, что бы текст не загружался в TRichEdit а заменялся напрямую в файле `.txt`?

```
procedure TForm4.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog.Execute then
    Editor.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
end;

procedure TForm4.btnReplaceClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  tblDictionary.First;
  while not tblDictionary.Eof do 
  begin
    Editor.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    P := 1;
    while P <> -1 do 
    begin
      P := Editor.FindText(tblDictionary.FieldByName('TextToFind').AsString, P, Length(Editor.Text), []);
      if P = -1 then Continue;
      Editor.SelStart := P;
      Editor.SelLength := Length(tblDictionary.FieldByName('TextToFind').AsString);
      Editor.ClearSelection;
      Editor.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
      Editor.SelAttributes.Color := clMaroon;
      Editor.SelText := tblDictionary.FieldByName('ReplaceWith').AsString;
      Inc(P, Editor.SelLength);
    end;
    Editor.Lines.EndUpdate;
    tblDictionary.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Немного причесал ваш вопрос, проверьте плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее:

1. Загрузить текст в `TStringList` например (а может и просто в `string`).
2. По количеству слов, выполнить замену при помощи `text := StringReplace(text, '1', '2', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])`.
3. Сохранить обратно в файл.